# Determinant of a matrix of monomial elements

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm using a $n\times m$ matrix $A$ defined over $\mathbb{N}^0$ to construct a $n\times m$ matrix $B$ such that $b_{ij} = x^{a_{ij}}$, for an indeterminate $x$. My questions are:

- Are these $B$ matrices known or studied in any field of mathematics. If so, can anyone point me to where I can learn more about it?
- In specific, I'm looking to see if we can say anything in general about $det(B)$ that we cannot say about $det(A)$?

Comment: See the following question and the answer provided by user1551: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813946/positive-definiteness-of-power-of-distance-matrix

Comment: @Daniel, thank you for your answer. That is interesting, but the answer assumes the values $a_{ij}$ are distinct, which I don't want to assume.