# Checking if a matrix that depends on the distance matrix is positive-definite

Tags: matrices, solution-verification, positive-definite

Let $H$ be a matrix of distances over $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $h_{ij}=d(s_i,s_j)$ where $d$ is  the Euclidean distance. Define
$$
\Gamma_{ij}=\exp\{-\alpha h_{ij}\}
$$
such that $\alpha>0$ fixed.
The book I'm reading says that it's enough to know that the smallest interpoint distance in $H$, off-diagonal entries, isn't zero in order to ensure that $\Gamma$ is positive-definite. However, I don't see why this is enough to ensure positive eigenvalues.

My attempt:
A matrix is p.d. iff its leading principal minors have positive determinants (Sylvester's criterion).

Let $P$ be a permutation matrix, then $P^\top = P^{-1}$ and $P\Gamma P^\top$ is similar to $\Gamma$. Thus, if exists $i\neq j$ such that $\Gamma_{ij}=0$, we may choose $P$ in order to move up the respective columns and rows and we get a leading principal minor that is equal to
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 
\end{array}\right]
$$
because the $\Gamma$ matrix is symmetric and all its diagonal entries are equal to one by construction. We know that the determinant of this matrix is $0$, therefore $PAP^\top$ isn't positive definite and we conclude that $A$ also isn't p.d.

Comment: $\alpha$ is a positive constant and $d$ is indeed the euclidean distance. sorry.

Comment: You state that $d$ is euclidean distance though I suspect this is incorrect and $d$ actually stands for *squared euclidean distance*.  If so, then this is a duplicate:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/813946/positive-definiteness-of-power-of-distance-matrix/

Comment: No, I'm sure it's the Euclidean distance. It's from the paper Covariance Tapering by Shaby and Rupert where they use the exponential radial basis function as a covariance function. The post is related but it's not a duplicate. I'd also like to check if my proof is correct.